# How to insert single line breaks in a Typing Effect in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I want to insert single line breaks in a Typing Effect in JavaScript.

I want my text to be like:

Hello,
My name is Tarkan,
I am 22 years old,
I am learning Front-End Web Development.

```
var i = 0;
var myInf = 'Hello, \n My name is Tarkan, \n I am 22 years old, \n I am learning Front-End Web Development';

function textTyping() {
  if (i < myInf.length) {
    document.getElementById("about").innerHTML += myInf.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(textTyping, 70);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load',textTyping());
```

I used \n but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newline character doesn't cause a line break in HTML. You must convert it to a `<br>` tag:

```js
let char = myInf.charAt(i);
if ( char === '\n' ) {
  char = '<br>';
}
document.getElementById("about").innerHTML += char;
```